# Splitting Field in Group Representation and Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading a textbook about group representation and it says:

> A field $\mathbb{F}$ is called a **splitting field** for a finite group $G$ if for every irreducible representation $\rho$ of $G$ the only intertwining operator (a morphism) between $\rho$ and itself are the scalar multiples $cI$ of the identity map $I$: $V_\rho \rightarrow V_\rho$, where $V_\rho$ is the vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

However, when I read the splitting field in Wiki, it says something about polynomial:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field

My question is: are both "splitting field" the same thing?  I am really confused about both definitions.

Comment: No they are not. The only thing they have in common is that they split something (one kind maximally splits polynomials whereas the other maximally splits representations).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin I think the connection is a bit stronger than that. A splitting field for a finite group in characteristic $0$ must contain the entries in the character table of $G$, which means that it must contain the splitting field of the minimal polynomial over ${\mathbb Q}$ of the union of the character values. But for some groups, such as $Q_8$, that alone does not give you a splitting field and you need to adjoin further irrationalities.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I agree for $Q_8$ the character values are all rational numbers but you need $\sqrt{-1}$ to actually represent the $2$-dimensional representation. Interestingly the splitting field of $D_4$ is $\mathbb{Q}$. It reminds me of this question a few days ago about which information does the character table convey. Apparently not the splitting field.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Also note that there does not exist a unique minimal splitting field. IIRC,  for $Q_8$ you can adjoin $\sqrt{-t}$ for many different values of $t$ and get a splitting field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a more general notion of splitting field for a finite-dimensional algebra and it integrates the two usages. So they are essentially the same. See [Proposition 7.12](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=f15FyZuZ3-4C&pg=PA107) and [Definition 8.2](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=f15FyZuZ3-4C&pg=PA118) in [T. Y. Lam, A First Course in Noncommutative Rings (2001)].